# Regular Expressions (Regex) Java

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I am new in Java. I am currently working with regular expressions (regex) in Java. 
Here is my question: I would like to remove : "Fund manager: CI Investments Inc." this part via my regular expression. How can I make it? 
The part of my code is given below.

CIG2306 /CIG3306 /CIG1306 Fund manager: CI Investments Inc. 
This is one of the output I read. I want to add a regex specially for this output. Because I do not want the part  Fund manager: CI Investments Inc to be removed from my output.

`public class Main { String text; private getFundCode(){ Pattern ptnFundCode = Pattern.compile("Fund code\\w?:\\s*(.*)[\\r\\n]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); Matcher mchFundCode = ptnFundCode.matcher(text); if(mchFundCode.find()){ System.out.println(mchFundCode.group(1)); //tempResult+=mchFundCode.group(1)+"; "; } else{ tempResult+="N/A; "; }`

Comment: Please show what code you have tried.

Comment: where is your code sample

Comment: Do you need to use regular expressions, or would a string replacement work too?

Comment: `public class Main {
    String text;
    private getFundCode(){
        Pattern ptnFundCode = Pattern.compile("Fund code\\w?:\\s*(.*)[\\r\\n]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher mchFundCode = ptnFundCode.matcher(text);
        if(mchFundCode.find()){
            System.out.println(mchFundCode.group(1));
            //tempResult+=mchFundCode.group(1)+"; ";
        }
        else{
            tempResult+="N/A; ";
        } `

Comment: please **edit** you question with this code

Answer (score 0):

just use [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

```
String before = "CIG2306 /CIG3306 /CIG1306 Fund manager: CI Investments Inc.";
String after = before.replace ("Fund manager: CI Investments Inc.", "");
```

If you really want to use `regex` to replace, then you can use `String.replaceAll` **but** what would your rule be?

**Maybe**

```
String after = before.replaceAll ("F.*", "");
```

Comment: Thanks I will use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
str.replaceAll("Fund manager: CI Investments Inc\.", "");
```

Comment: It will not remove all the Fund managers in my text, right? Because I will use them in another column of my output.

Comment: @Chrisxx I didn't quite follow you but it will indeed remove all the `Fund manager`s and the following text which I've placed in `replaceAll` method.